# Sencha Touch 2.3.0 NestedList doesn't display child items when tapping but only root items

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

**Update:** 
[Demo of the problem](http://test.joquery.com/SenchaNestedListProblem/)

I'm pretty new to Sencha Touch and am trying to get a NestedList working.

I've set up two model files, a store with an ajax proxy that loads a local json file and the view containing the `NestedList`.

The `NestedList` displays the root elements from my json file, so that's all working so far.

But when I click on one of those items, it animates the view but the resulting list is only showing the parent items again, but this time with a back button in the titlebar:

[image: First time] [image: After clicking on an item]

I really don't get what I am doing wrong here.

**JSON** (compact)

```
{
"countries":[
{"name":"Germany","countryCode":"de","cities":[
    {"name":"Berlin"},{"name":"Muenchen"}]},
{"name":"France","countryCode":"fr","cities":[
    {"name":"Paris"},{"name":"Lyon"}]},
{"name":"United Kingdom","countryCode":"uk","cities":[
    {"name":"London"},{"name":"Leicester"}]}]
}
```

**Models**

1. City:

   ```
   Ext.define('MyApp.model.City', {
       extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
       config: {
           fields: [{ name: 'name', type: 'string' }]
       }
   });
   ```
2. Country:

   ```
   Ext.define('MyApp.model.Country', {
       extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

       require: [
           "MyApp.model.City"
       ],

       config: {
           fields: [
               { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
               { name: 'countryCode', type: 'string' }
           ],
           hasMany: [{ model: "MyApp.model.City", name: "cities" }]
       },
   });
   ```

**TreeStore**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.CountryTreeStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

    config: {
        autoLoad: true,
        model: "MyApp.model.Country",
        defaultRootProperty: "countries",
        proxy: {
            type: "ajax",
            url: "/data/data.json",
            reader: {
                type: "json"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**part from the view**

```
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'nestedlist',
        store: "CountryTreeStore",
        displayField: "name"
    }
]
```

**Update:**
Setting a breakpoint in the `load` event listener of the `TreeStore` (`proxy`) and inspecting the "loaded" store object shows, that it has a `cities` property with the correct data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hm I've tried to refactor your problem. When I set the key "cities" in the json to "countries", or the same key from the previous level, it seems to work. So it's your "hasMany"-relation which is not working. I've never tried to do it this way. So when you remove the "hasMany"-relation, and change the json to this, it will work:

```
[{
"countries":[
{"name":"Germany","countryCode":"de","countries":[
{"name":"Berlin", leaf: true},{"name":"Muenchen", leaf: true}]},
{"name":"France","countryCode":"fr","countries":[
{"name":"Paris", leaf: true},{"name":"Lyon", leaf: true}]},
{"name":"United Kingdom","countryCode":"uk","countries":[
{"name":"London", leaf: true},{"name":"Leicester", leaf: true}]}]
}]
```

*and with "leaf: true" you can listen to the "leafitemtap" event, to do something when you reach the end of the tree.*

Where have you found the example with the "hasMany"-relation? Maybe there's just a little thing missing ;)

Comment: I've found the example in the sencha docs: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/guide/models-section-associations. But just by reading it again I realized that I've omitted the `belongsTo` property and the `foreign key` in the `City Model`. I'm going to add them and try it out.

Comment: Hm yes I tried this, but the relation gives you the possibility to use the data of the related model. So you can access the related model data within your templates etc. But I think this can't be used within a nested list. All examples I found about nested lists use the same "keys" in the json.

Comment: I've added the association and the corresponding id's and foreign keys in the json file and tried it but the app hangs after tapping a parent item. It slides in the next view and shows a loading dialog that never disappears. You can't even do anything inside the browser tab only force close it by ending the task.

Comment: I'm gonna accept your answer here, because it seems to be the only way how `NestedLists` work. So you can't directly work with your "server side" objects serialized as json but have to "map" them to a specialized viewmodel sencha can work with.

Comment: That's why I don't use `NestedList`, I use a self written one which uses a relation on `parent_id` because I don't have/want an nested json.

Comment: Thanky you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to set `leaf: true` on the last item level? `{"name":"Muenchen", "leaf": true}`

Comment: I've updated the demo at http://test.joquery.com/SenchaNestedListProblem/ But it doesn't show any effect.

Comment: have you tried to use the data like in the kitchen sink: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.NestedList  there the "displayField" is always "text". Maybe it's because the "hasMany" property in your model.

Comment: Following the guide code by code led me to a working example. I guess it has something do to with the models and the defaultRootProperty / rootProperty (on the reader) combination. But that's just a guess.

Comment: Of course the "root" should be set in the reader like so `rootProperty: "countries"`